# num2str((rng'* (sp(t)-sa(t))) + sa(t),'%2.2g')

Tags: matlab

I have a question on the following line on a MATLAB script.  What does '%2.2g' mean in this line?  I know it is use to format a number notation.  Are there other options as to changing it to a 10^1, 10^2, 10^3?  Can anyone find some resources for me to read?

```
num2str((rng'* (sp(t)-sa(t))) + sa(t),'%2.2g')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `%a.bg` :

   - **a**: stands for the width of the number
   - **b**: the number of decimals printed.
   - **g**: chooses the more compact of %e or %f. (Insignificant zeroes do not print.)

   For example:

   ```
   >> sprintf('%2.2g', 1.23)

   ans =

   1.2

   >> sprintf('%2.2g', 123000)

   ans =

   1.2e+05
   ```

   Note that it rounds the result.
2. For exponential notation just use something `%2.2e`.
3. For formatting rules just look at the documentation: [Formatting Text- Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html)